# powershell command to terminate/cancel a script

Tags: powershell

Is there any powershell command available to terminate a powershell script? I have used `Exit 1`, but that doesn't help me.  Even I have tried throw that also gave some error. This is the script I have tried.  I want the script to stop when the service status is stopped.

```
$EMAgent1 = get-wmiobject win32_service | where-object {($_.Name -eq 'oim12cAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'oimagent12c2Agent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'oimagent10gAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'GFarmEM10gAgent') -or ($_.Name -eq 'GFarmEM11gAgent')} | format-list name | Out-String

$AgentName1 = $EMAgent.Split(":")[1].Trim()

$EMStatus1 = get-wmiobject win32_service | where-object {$_.Name -eq $AgentName} | format-list state | Out-String
$AgentStatus1 = $EMStatus.Split(":")[1].Trim()

if ($AgentName1 -eq $null)
{
    $AgentName1 = "Unavailable"
}
else
{
    $AgentName1 = "$AgentName1"
}
if ($AgentStatus1 -eq "Stopped")
{
    Exit 1
}
Else 
{

}
```

Comment: [System.Environment]::Exit(0)

Comment: _I have used Exit 1 but that doesn't help me_ Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40466460/check-windows-services-status-using-powershell

Comment: Exit 1 work great. You have problem in your script, try to put breakpoint in Exit 1 and check you script in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Service` instead since it's faster and easier to use.

It's more advisable to search for the desired services to begin with, rather than getting all services and discarding every mismatch later. That way you don't need to handle an empty list of services because it's filled right from the start anyway.

Your desired script may look like this:

```
$AgentList='oim12cAgent','oimagent12c2Agent','oimagent10gAgent','GFarmEM10gAgent','GFarmEM11gAgent'

foreach ($AgentService in $AgentList) {
    if ((Get-Service $AgentService -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Status -like '*stopped*') {
        break
        } else {
            Write-Host "do stuff"
            }
    }
```